# What are my options in saving lots of dynamically created uobjects and restoring links to/between them?

Tags: c++, serialization, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a game with lots of dynamically created uobjects some of which are interlinked with pointers. UObjects are generally created and stored in manager actors. The game is still in active development. I need to save all of that in a way that requires minimum effort in maintaining after object modification.

Tried to put all of the object fields in to a save struct and assigning an ID to an object. But any modification to an object requires you to change the save struct which is tedious. Also, restoring links in cases where one UObject links to another is always a problem to solve.
What are my options in minimizing the tedious work? Is there a plugin that can handle saving UObjects and restoring links? Or even just making a level snapshot

Comment: Treat this like a graph problem.

Comment: might help https://unrealcommunity.wiki/savegame-pointers-and-structs-8wlg0qms

Comment: If the manager class stores pointers to created objects in an array, you treat their index in that array as the id (i.e. whenever you need to save an object reference, save instead the result of a `TArray::Find`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a plugin.

I don't use `EasyMultiSave`, however I purchased it to see how they handled some situations. It is really well setup, and continuously maintained.

- [Easy Multi Save](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/easy-multi-save)

It does support saving and loading dynamically spawned objects. And their references. It also utilizes the `SaveGame` checkbox already existing in the property details panel.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Does it also save object arrays?

Comment: Well. After some testing, plugin does not appear to save and load object references and you have to restore them yourself. It does not appear to save non actor objects at all, tbh. If there is  any way of getting the behaviour you described, please do so

Comment: @SunGrow does it work if you use soft references? That's how I would try to do it. If you load an object and the other objects that it has references to don't exist, they'll become null references. But with Soft Object References, you maintain the path to the object, even if it is currently null. That way all the objects can load, and you don't lose references.